# How do I get a delegated property class in Kotlin to support multiple property types?

Tags: kotlin, delegates

I'm trying to use delegated properties in Kotlin to provide some type safety to application preferences that are persisted to a non-typed store. The store is semanitcally a bit like some type of `Map<String,Any>`, although it doesn't implement that specific class.

The problem i have is that it doesn't appear possible for a single delegate class to implement `getValue` and `setValue` for more than one type.

If this is the type-safe `SomePreferences` class that other applications will call to get/set `preferenceOne` and `preferenceTwo`:

```kotlin
class SomePreferences {
    private val myDelegate = MyPreferenceStorageImpl()
    var preferenceOne: Boolean by myDelegate
    var preferenceTwo: String by myDelegate
}
```

However, if I try and create `MyPreferencesStorageImpl`, it tries to look something like this:

```kotlin
class MyPreferenceStorageImpl() {
    operator fun getValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, property: KProperty<*>): Boolean {
        TODO("Read from underlying store, transforming the read value as a boolean")
    }

    operator fun setValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, property: KProperty<*>, b: Boolean) {
        TODO("Write to underlying store, transforming the value from a Boolean")
    }

    operator fun getValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        TODO("Read from underlying store, transforming value to a String")
    }

    operator fun setValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, property: KProperty<*>, s: String) {
        TODO("Write to underlying store, transforming given value to a string")
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work, because I've got two methods who only differ by return type, which is a conflict.

I've a couple of half-baked ideas on how to solve this, including trying to subclass `Map<String, Any>` in some way, or maybe provide a type-specific implementation per preference type (ew), or generics (somehow) but these don't feel particularly right.

Am I missing an obviously better approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you won't be using the delegate on properties with a type parameter as their type...

You can make it generic:

```
class MyPreferenceStorageImpl() {
    operator fun <T> getValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        TODO("Read from underlying store, transforming the read value as a T")
    }

    operator fun <T> setValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, property: KProperty<*>, b: T) {
        TODO("Write to underlying store, transforming the value from a T")
    }
}
```

Note that when you return from `getValue`, you would need to do an unchecked cast. This cannot be 100% safe, because `T` could have its own type parameters. You can at least check something like this though:

```
// suppose you've got the value from storage and it's now stored in "returnValue"
if ((property.returnType.classifier as? KClass<*>)?.isInstance(returnValue) == true) {
    return returnValue as T
} else {
    // something went wrong, returnValue is not an instance of T
}
```

If you need to handle each type (`String`, `Int`, `Boolean`) differently, you can do:

```
when (property.returnType) {
    typeOf<String>() -> TODO()
    typeOf<Int>() -> TODO()
    typeOf<Boolean>() -> TODO()
    else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was heading in this direction and thinking that I'd have to generify over the MyPreferenceStorageImpl, (and then createa  concrete instance for each type). It never occurred to me that you could just generify on the functions themselves and that kotlin would accept that.

Comment: @growse Making `MyPreferenceStorageImpl` generic and creating multiple instances works too!

Comment: True! Just less useful in my case :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without the reflection library, you can use reified types.

```
class MyPreferenceStorageImpl {
    inline operator fun <reified T> getValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return when (T::class) {
            Boolean::class -> TODO("Read from underlying store, transforming the read value as a Boolean")
            String::class -> TODO("Read from underlying store, transforming the read value as a String")
            else -> error("${T::class} is an unsupported property type for delegation.")
        } as T

    }

    inline operator fun <reified T> setValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        when (T::class) {
            Boolean::class -> TODO("Write to underlying store, transforming the value from a Boolean")
            String::class -> TODO("Write to underlying store, transforming the value from a String")
            else -> error("${T::class} is an unsupported property type for delegation.")
        }
    }
}
```

To prevent compiled code growth from the inlining, you can pass through to non-reified functions:

```
class MyPreferenceStorageImpl {
    inline operator fun <reified T> getValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, property: KProperty<*>): T =
        getValue(somePreferences, T::class)

    fun <T> getValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, class: KClass<T>)
        return when (class) {
            Boolean::class -> TODO("Read from underlying store, transforming the read value as a Boolean")
            String::class -> TODO("Read from underlying store, transforming the read value as a String")
            else -> error("${T::class} is an unsupported property type for delegation.")
        } as T

    }

    inline operator fun <reified T> setValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) =
        setValue(somePreferences, T::class, value)

    fun <T> setValue(somePreferences: SomePreferences, class: KClass<T>, value: T) {
        when (class) {
            Boolean::class -> TODO("Write to underlying store, transforming the value from a Boolean")
            String::class -> TODO("Write to underlying store, transforming the value from a String")
            else -> error("${T::class} is an unsupported property type for delegation.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this too. Though if many types were supported, and the preferences were used in a lot of places, wouldn't a large amount of code be inlined to many call sites? I feared that this could potentially increase the code size by a significant amount. Since you can also get the type from `property`, I chose not to use `reified`. But now that I think about it, loading `kotlin.reflect` is just as bad, haha!

Comment: @Sweeper, Yes, definitely some pros and cons. One option would be to overload these functions with non-reified versions that have a KClass parameter, and then pass through to that. Then since the inline function is a one-liner, it's not really expanding the amount of code at the call sites.

Comment: I was going to ask about reification, but you've pre-empted that. I know that reification increases inline size, but would this happen at every place that the preference property (delegated to the Storage class) is referenced throughout the codebase, as opposed to once just for the getter/setter?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems probably the code growth would only be at the site of each property, not every use of them. I edited the answer to show how you could do it without any code growth.

Comment: Ah, I've just noticed that my delegate is an interface, and you can't create inline reified functions on an interface :(

Comment: You can define inline extension functions on an interface. Extension functions work for making something into a property delegate candidate. @growse